# Can I add a subclass to a list made of the superclass? Why isn't this working?

Tags: java

I have three different classes, the Espacio class (which means "place"), the Despacho class ("office") and the Centro class ("Building"). Both Despacho and Centro are subclasses of Espacio.

Supposedly a building holds different places - classes - but also Despachos (offices). I can't figure out how to add some places of the type offices, to the list of places in a building, being able to know that they are offices later on. Sorry, trying to explain it my best.

This is some code:

```
public EspacioImpl(TipoEspacio tipo, String nombre, Integer capacidad, Integer planta){
    checkCapacidad(capacidad);
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
    this.planta = planta;
}

public DespachoImpl(TipoEspacio tipo, String nombre, Integer capacidad, 
        Integer planta, Set<Profesor> profesores){
    super(tipo, nombre, capacidad, planta);
    tipo = TipoEspacio.OTRO;
    checkNumeroProfesores(profesores, capacidad);
    this.profesores = profesores;
    checkTipo(tipo);

}   

public CentroImpl(String nombre, String direccion, Integer numeroPlantas, Integer numeroSotanos){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    checkPlantas(numeroPlantas);
    checkSotanos(numeroSotanos);
    this.numeroPlantas = numeroPlantas;
    this.numeroSotanos = numeroSotanos;
    this.espacios = new HashSet<Espacio>();
}
```

This is the function I'm using to add places to the espacios list.

```
@Override
public void nuevoEspacio(Espacio e) {
    Espacio aux1 = e;
    Integer plantaEspacioE = aux1.getPlanta();
    Integer sotanos = getNumeroSotanos() * -1;
    Integer plantas = getNumeroPlantas() -1;
    if(!(plantaEspacioE <= plantas && plantaEspacioE >= sotanos)) {
        throw new ExcepcionCentroOperacionNoPermitida("Planta para nuevo espacio invalida");
    }
    espacios.add(e);

}
```

When I test it trying to add places to the building, it works, but when I try to add an office, it doesn't do anything.

Tell me if you need anything else.
Espacio class: [http://pastebin.com/xF3STyBM](https://pastebin.com/xF3STyBM)

Despacho (office) class: [http://pastebin.com/vAdwnjxW](https://pastebin.com/vAdwnjxW)

Centro (building) class: [http://pastebin.com/ckasJBjX](https://pastebin.com/ckasJBjX)

Comment: What is `espacios`? Provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Normally classes in a building. This is something to implement it:   Espacio b1 = new EspacioImpl(TipoEspacio.EXAMEN, "Krauss", 50, 1);

TipoEspacio.Examen = kind of class. Krauss = name, 50 = capacity, 1 = floor of the building it's at.

Comment: You seem to be showing only the constructors. Show the class enclosing the constructor as well. Also show the Office class. Also show the code adding places to the building and the line where the office cant be added.You are asking one thing but showing something completely different. How do we answer your question?

Comment: @bot added as pastebins, sorry, my knowledge is not too high.

Comment: Show the code that is creating and adding objects to the list. Show the creation of the espacios list.

Comment: @bot this is my test code, http://pastebin.com/cpDxqxFn, it also tests some other things. More importantly When it tries to add de1 and de2 to the centro, it doesn't work. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can add subclass objects to the list made by superclass. Actually, you should create your instances from superclass as subclass and after that you can add them into the list. To give an example:

```
Superclass test = new Subclass();
listofsuper.add(test);
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to add an office to a list of spaces in a building; then later on, you need to be able to know that space is an office and use it like an office.

See if this helps you..

```
  List<Espacio> spaces = new ArrayList<Espacio>();

  Despacho office = new DespacoImpl();

  spaces.add(office);


  //Later on in the program, when you need to know that espacio = despachos....

  for(Espacio space : spaces) {
     if(space instanceof Despacho) {
         //Space is an office
         Despacho office = (Despacho) space;
     }
   }
```

I don't know if this entirely addresses your question; the key thing here is the `instanceof` operator, which will tell you whether the space is an office or not.

Consider, however, moving this into a method of `Espacio` if every different type of space has the same operation.  For example, if the only reason that you want to know whether a space is an office or not is to measure its size, then it makes more sense to make a `getSize()` method on `Espacio`, rather than a series of "if it's an office, then do this, if it's a building, then do this" statements.